# How can I redirect STDOUT of a subprocess called by a tkinter app into a tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, asynchronous, subprocess

I want to run a compiler from my tkinter application. The STDOUT of the compiler shall be copied into a text widget of my tkinter application: At any time the compiler creates a message at STDOUT, this message shall immediately get visible in the text widget. The problem is, that I always get the STDOUT messages in the text widget after the compiler has finished, but not during the compiler runs.

As finding a solution was difficult for me I decided to create a question here, as someone other may have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When my tkinter application is blocked during the time the compiler runs it will not be able to update the text widget. To solve this I used a thread. The start() function of the thread terminates immediately and so my tkinter application is not blocked during the compiler runs. In the thread now the compiler has to be started. The thread must also not be blocked during the time the compiler runs, as the thread must copy the STDOUT messages of the compiler into the text widget of my tkinter application. To achieve this I used subprocess.Popen(). It starts the compiler "asynchronously" and allows to access the messages by "for line in process.stdout:".  In my example code instead of a compiler call I used a Python snippet to create messages at STDOUT. Please see my example code:

```
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
def command():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")
    process = subprocess.Popen('Python -c "for i in range(10000): print(i)"',
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                text=True)
    for line in process.stdout:
        text.insert(tk.END, line)
        text.see   (tk.END)
def run_command():
    thread = Thread(target=command)
    thread.start()
root   = tk.Tk()
text   = tk.Text(root)
button = tk.Button(root, text="run", command=run_command)
text  .grid()
button.grid()
root  .mainloop()
```